# Obtener valor de objetos repetidos en una Array

Tags: javascript, json

Hola muy buenos días a todos, espero estén bien, es que tengo el siguiente JSON

```
'product': [
{
   "Line_Type": "12345",
   "Plan": "TRIO",
   "Product": "TELEFONICA",
   "Product_Type": "Secundario",
   "Service": "00009",
   "State": "ACTIVO",
   "Technology": "NN"
},
 {
   "Line_Type": "123456",
   "Plan": "TRIO",
   "Product": "INTERNET",
   "Product_Type": "Primario",
   "Service": "000091",
   "State": "ACTIVO",
   "Technology": "NN"
}, {
   "Line_Type": "123457",
   "Plan": "TRIO",
   "Product": "CABLE",
   "Product_Type": "Primario",
   "Service": "0000912",
   "State": "ACTIVO",
   "Technology": "NN"
},
]
```

Y estoy buscando recorrer ese array en una función para que solo busque por `"Product_Type"` y si es == a `"Primario"` me devuelva el valor de `"Product"` de ese objeto.

Estoy haciendolo de la siguiente forma

```
var data = 'product': [
 {
    "Line_Type": "12345",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "TELEFONICA",
    "Product_Type": "Secundario",
    "Service": "00009",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 },
  {
    "Line_Type": "123456",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "INTERNET",
    "Product_Type": "Primario",
    "Service": "000091",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 }, {
    "Line_Type": "123457",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "CABLE",
    "Product_Type": "Primario",
    "Service": "0000912",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 },
]

function Buscador(){
    switch (data){
    case ('Product_Type' == "Primario") :
      return data.product[0].Product || null
      break;
  }
};
```

Pero no estoy recibiendo nada :/, agradecería un poco de ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar el metodo `find` para buscar coincidencias dentro de un arreglo de objetos, el metodo find **buscara un unico resultado.**

Si necesitas **buscar multiples resultados**, te recomiendo usar el metodo `filter`, para obtener todos los productos de tipo primario en tu arreglo y quedaria de la siguiente forma:

```js
var data = [
 {
    "Line_Type": "12345",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "TELEFONICA",
    "Product_Type": "Secundario",
    "Service": "00009",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 },
  {
    "Line_Type": "123456",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "INTERNET",
    "Product_Type": "Primario",
    "Service": "000091",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 }, {
    "Line_Type": "123457",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "CABLE",
    "Product_Type": "Primario",
    "Service": "0000912",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 },
]
//Find (unico resultado)
let productoPrimario =data.find(x=>x.Product_Type == "Primario").Product


console.log(productoPrimario)

let productosPrimarios =data.filter(x=>x.Product_Type == "Primario")

console.log(productosPrimarios)
```

[Documentacion filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

[Documentacion find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Answer (score 0):

No estoy muy seguro cómo buscas que se recorra el array, si dentro de un ciclo, o que la función reciba de parámetro el array y la función se encargue de recorrerlo, que es lo que tendría más sentido; así que eso hice, cree una función que recibe un arreglo como parámetro, y lo único que hace es: con una condicional revisar la propiedad Product_Type, y si es "Primario"; en un arreglo nuevo va a pushear la propiedad Product de ese mismo objeto. Espero te sirva.

```js
var data = [
 {
    "Line_Type": "12345",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "TELEFONICA",
    "Product_Type": "Secundario",
    "Service": "00009",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 },
  {
    "Line_Type": "123456",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "INTERNET",
    "Product_Type": "Primario",
    "Service": "000091",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 }, {
    "Line_Type": "123457",
    "Plan": "TRIO",
    "Product": "CABLE",
    "Product_Type": "Primario",
    "Service": "0000912",
    "State": "ACTIVO",
    "Technology": "NN"
 },
]

const returnPrimario = (array) => {
    let response = []
  array.forEach(element => {
    if(element['Product_Type'] === 'Primario'){
        response.push(element['Product'])
    }
  })
  return response
}

console.log(returnPrimario(data))
```

Comment: Pero si quisiera devolverlos cada uno en un objeto independiente? 
```
return {
     'Primero': (Primer Objeto)
     'Segundo': (Segundo Objeto)
}; 
```
Podría hacerlo así? Para no devolverlos en un Array